# Django calling a specific field in a table

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

So basically I have this for loop which pulls each individual professor based on the specific attributes of that table.

```
<ul>
    {% for major in major_choice %}

    <li>{{major.ProfessorName}}, {{major.ProfessorRating}}, {{major.Major}}</li>

    {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

The thing is I wanted to basically create a header tag and simply add the major from one of the results so my goal was something like this..

```
<h1> {{major_choice.Major}} </h1>
```

Also this specific template, already has a filter set so the database only has for instance ALL of one major, ill post an image so you can see what I mean.[image]

So I was hoping that h1 tag would make a "Asian American Studies" header

Comment: If you are sure that they all have the same `Major` value you can use `major_choice.0.Major` to use the first result in your queryset. Otherwise see [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag.

Comment: Thank you that has resolved my issue you are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selcuk response has resolved my issue. Thank you, the solution was in fact

```
major_choice.0.Major
```

Please give credit to him for answering this question.